# How do I implement a like counter using PHP, jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on creating a like counter for quotes. I am trying to increment the like counter when the user clicks on the like button and display the number of likes.

Problems I encountered:

1. Like counter gets incremented when I refresh the page (Not because I am actually hit the like button).
2. I tried implementing jQuery for the updation of the like counter in real time but failed :(

I referred to all the QnA related to this couldn't find the desired solution. I went through this [question][PHP/MySQL Like Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401141/php-mysql-like-button), and made the necessary changes but now there is no updation in the database when I click the button.

```
This is the code for one quote.

<div class="testimonial text-sm is-revealing">
 <div class="testimonial-inner">
  <div class="testimonial-main">
   <div class="testimonial-body">
   <p id="q1">
       <?php
         $sql = "select quotes from voted where voted.quote_id = 1";
         $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         echo "$row[0]";
      ?></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-footer">
   <div class="testimonial-name">
    <button method="POST" action='' name="like" type="submit" class="like"><b>Like</b></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST['like'])){
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","success");
        $sql = "UPDATE voted SET likes = likes+1 WHERE voted.quote_id = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        }
      ?>
       <label>
        <?php
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","success");
          $sql = "SELECT likes from voted WHERE voted.quote_id = 1";
          $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          echo "$row[0]";
         ?>
        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="btn" id="clipboard" onclick="copyFunction('#q1')"></button>                    
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make the like counter implement when I click on the like button?

How do I implement jQuery and AJAX to this, so that the counter is updated without a page refresh?

Please pardon my poor code structure.

Thanks for any help.

P.S [This how a single quote will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZxbV.png)

Comment: Sidenote: You shouldn't put variables in quotes like `echo "$row[0]";`. People will argue that it's valid, yes it is, but it's bad practice and can have sideeffects. Concatenate strings with `.` and you are fine. `echo $row[0];`

Comment: `button` does not have a `method` or `action` attribute, these belong to `form`.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, for noticing it. I enclosed the button tag within a form tag and now there is a page refresh and my like counter is getting updated when I click the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need three things for an asynchronous setup like this to work:

1. Your back-end script to handle ajax requests
2. Your front-end page
3. Your JQuery script to send ajax requests and receive data

Your back-end PHP script would look something like this (async.php):

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['get_quotes'])) {
         $sql = "select quotes from voted where voted.quote_id = 1";
         $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         echo "$row[0]";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","success");
        $sql = "UPDATE voted SET likes = likes+1 WHERE voted.quote_id = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }
?>
```

Your front-end page will include an element with an ID to hook onto with the JQuery, and a button with a class or ID to capture the click event (page.html):

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="core.js"></script>
    <body>
    <button id="increment-like" value="Like" type="button" />

    <p id="like-count">
    </p>
</body>
<html>
```

Finally, your JavaScript file should look something like this, for a basic ajax request using JQuery (core.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initially grab the database value and present it to the view

    $('#like-count').text(getDatabaseValue());

    $('#increment-like').on('click', function() {
        incrementDatabaseValue();
    });
});

function getDatabaseValue() {
     $.post("async.php",
        {
            get_quotes: true
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // check status here
            //return value
        return data;
        });
}

function incrementDatabaseValue() {
     $.post("async.php",
        {
            like: true
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // check status here

        // update view
        $('#like-count').text(getDatabaseValue());
        });
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should be clear and detailed enough to get you on the right track.